# Selecting values in one column until the sum of another column reaches a value

Tags: python

I have two columns Demand and square footage, want to maximize demand until a the capacity it reached (30 sqft).

| Demand | square footage |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 12 | 5 |
| 7 | 10 |
| 13 | 20 |

I know this is basically a solver question but i have too many values, this is my first time creating something like this.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: can you clarify if you want to maximise demand based on the rolling value of sq ftg that is below 30 ?